# Applescript equivalent of "jump to line n#"

Tags: java, applescript

I've made a text game using applescript and as its got about 60 ending it's pretty long, so I want a bit of code like in java that lets you jump to a different part of the code.

Does such a thing exist in applescript?

Comment: There's no goto in Java so I'm not sure what the "equivalent" would be in Applescript

Comment: Continue functions quite a bit like a 'goto' equivalent in Java.

Comment: Look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html and see if it helps

Comment: Thanks for letting me know guys, I've only recently learned applescript so it's good to know these things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Applescript does not have line number goto commands. You have to structure conditional functions as separate handlers, and then call each handler as needed.

```
if thisBoolean then
    runThisHandler()
else if thatBoolean then
    runThatHandler()
else
    -- do something else
end
```

Comment: Not the answer I was hoping for but its true and helpful. Thanks dude :)